# Spark write to Hive mistaken table_name as Partition spec and throws "Partition spec contains non-partition columns" error

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, hive

My Hive table was defined with `PARTITIONED BY (ds STRING, model STRING)`
And when writing to the table in PySpark, I did

```
output_df
  .repartition(250)
  .write
  .mode('overwrite')
  .format('parquet')\
  .partitionBy('ds', 'model')\
  .saveAsTable('{table_schema}.{table_name}'.format(table_schema=table_schema, 
  table_name=table_name))
```

However I encountered the following error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.ValidationFailureSemanticException: Partition spec {ds=2019-10-06, model=p1kr, table_name=drv_projection_table} contains non-partition columns
```

It seems Spark or Hive mistaken `table_name` as a partition. My S3 path for the table is `s3://some_path/qubole/table_name=drv_projection_table`, but `table_name` wasn't specified as part of the partition.

Comment: What is the `table_name` when you're using it in your `saveAsTable`?

Comment: It's `drv_projection_table`, the same value that the error message considered as a partition key.

Comment: It looks like the whole thing `table_name=drv_projection_table` should be the name of your table if you don't want Hive to interpret it as a partition spec. I'm not sure how did you manage to create it though (with `=` being a special character), see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11699.

Comment: @daydayup Did you solve the issue? I'm facing the same issue.